# Sending django signals from django-admin command?

Tags: python, django, django-signals, django-manage.py

I have an unsual problem. In my Django application I use signals to send emails.
All of signals work except for the one fired from django-admin command - django.core.management.base.NoArgsCommand (which is run through manage.py).

I checked my signal in different places, it works except for this place.

Here's the code where I send the signal:

```
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    help = "Send email advertisement expiration reminder to users"

    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        from app.models import Advertisement, User
        from app.signals import ad_expires
        from datetime import datetime
        start=datetime(datetime.now().year, datetime.now().month, datetime.now().day+4,0,0)
        end=datetime(datetime.now().year,datetime.now().month,datetime.now().day+4,23,59)
        ads=Advertisement.objects.filter(visible_till__gte=start).filter(visible_till__lte=end)
        for ad in ads:
            ad_expires.send(self,ad=ad, user=ad.user)
        print "Expiration reminders sent to %s users" % len(ads)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Also, is there any easier way to check date within one day?

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut is :

```
start = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=4)
end = start + timedelta(days=1)
ads=Advertisement.objects.filter(visible_till__gte=start).filter(visible_till__lt=end)
```

Can you post your project structure here? Your code looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of, is that the signal handler hasn't been registered at the time the django-admin function executes. You can check this by preceding the listener with a `print` statement and running your management command.

Try putting the signal listener into the `app/__init__.py` file. Since you're accessing the `app` package, everything in `__init__.py` should execute, registering the listener.

Comment: I tried putting print statements where I register signals and where I connect signal to the handler function. Everywhere it works, so it's not the problem with registering the signal...